# problem with a very simple logical javascript program

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a very simple exercise, they gave me 2 variables a and b, if a is falsy so we will assign b to result.

We must not use the If statement and the ternary operator.

Here is the suggestions they gave me :

```
function run(a, b) {
let result

...

return result
}
```

Could you please give me some ideas ? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR):

```
const result = a || b;
```

JavaScript logical operators use [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation), so `b` will only be evaluated if `a` is falsy.

---

In a snippet:

```js
function run(a, b) {
  return a || b;
}

console.log(run('a', 'b'));
console.log(run('', 'b'));
console.log(run(0, 'b'));
```